# Change size of image with respect to the size of frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, image-resizing

Hi I am adding an image to my application and I want to resize the image if I change the size of my application window. How can I achieve it. here it is how I am adding it.Thanks WL

```
        ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("folder/image.jpg"));

        JLabel label =  new JLabel("", logo, JLabel.CENTER);
        BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
        JPanel upperpanel = new JPanel(border);
        upperpanel.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        add(upperpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: Seems like you missed to add your label somewhere, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

`Image` has the method

```
public Image getScaledInstance(int width, int height, int hints)
```

Comment: I am not sure, but since the Image is added to the JLabel, so isn't JLabel's size will define the size of the image now.

Comment: @Gagandeep Bali no, resize for image ended on size of pixels +1